# How can I make a pepper robot choregraphe app appear on the tablet to launch it?

Tags: pepper, choregraphe

I've read in the pepper/aldebaran documentation as well as in posts here that it is possible to launch pepper behaviours directly from the tablet. My problem is that the projects and behaviours that I create with choregraphe do not appear on the tablet. I can launch the installed package/project without any problem using the trigger conditions, but have no idea how to launch them on the tablet. Thus my questions is where can I find them on the tablet. I ticked the box "may start on user request" in the properties dialog.

Comment: What version are you using?
Choregraph projects can utlize the tablet (display html/process input) but cannot be started from the tablet.
Android projects could be started from the tablet.
Where did you read "it is possible to launch pepper behaviours directly from the tablet" ? 
Please provide a link so we could clarify misunderstanding.

Comment: Hi thanks, for your reply! We are using Pepper and Choregraphe in NAOQi V2.5.10.7 You can read this in almost all tutorials at the Aldebaran site e.g.:  [link](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/getting_started/samples/sample_dance1.html)

_italic_ Launch the application.

Through the tablet

    In the App Launcher, press the application’s icon.   

In the meantime I have developed several applications both with choregraphe and via the Python SDK that I could launch by trigger sentences or senors events, but I was puzzled by the comment at the tutorials sites.

Answer (score 0):

This was also new to me but i figured out something.

- In Choregraph you need to start the application "j-tablet-browser"
- Now a promt will appear on the Tablet "Allow USB Debugging on Tablet"
- Select "Allow"
- Now a promt will appear on the Tablet "Select a Home app"
- Select "Launcher 3"
- Now you can open an Android app that is called RALViewer.
- This App will show you the icons of your Choregraph projects that are installed.
- Then after restart Pepper, the tablet should show the normal Android
  screen and ask you again to Select a Home app. You can also make "Laucher 3" the default starting app.

Maybe it is also possible to set RAL Viewer as the default starting app so you dont need to navigate in Android after startup.

I dont know if thats what was meant in the tutorials, but it offers a way to start your app from the tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for explanation! I came already across the RALViewer but it did not show the applications that I have uploaded. In the meantime I have experienced that newly uploaded apps do not appear immediately, but only after a reboot or any other condition that I coul not determine yet. Anyhow this seems to answer the question.