# How to create apps launcher at Pepper's tablet

Tags: pepper, choregraphe

I would like to have the Tablet showing the apps that i installed inside Pepper robot when it turned on. Following the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53920645/how-can-i-make-a-pepper-robot-choregraphe-app-appear-on-the-tablet-to-launch-it), i couldn't get any prompt when i connected Pepper via Choregraphe and start application "j-tablet-browser". The robot is running NaoQi version 2.5.10.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [this application](https://github.com/softbankrobotics-labs/app-launcher) that should do just that (I haven't tested it myself).

For more details, you can also look at [the documentation on making applications that use the tablet](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-naoqi-2-5/naoqi-developer-guide/creating-application/using-peppers-tablet).

(Normally you don't need to do anything with j-tablet-browser, unlike what the comment you linked said)